# Simulating draws from a negative binomial

Tags: distributions, sampling, negative-binomial-distribution

I am looking for a way to simulate draws from a negative binomial distribution for a computational experiment on biological sequencing data. I am using a high performance package which only has certain distributions however, and though I know that gamma+poisson draws would give me the required simulation, the package lacks the latter. Here is a list of the distributions I have: [uniform, triangular, beta, exponential, gaussian, lognormal, vonmises, weibull, pareto, gamma]. Is there a simple approximation I can use from any of these functions that would require the least computational complexity (i.e. dont loop over creating many random draws for a single sample).

Comment: All the distribution you have are continuous. I think you need at least one discrete distribution because the negative binomial distribution is a discrete distribution.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to any. Although I do have access to a random choice from a list which would simulate a uniform over a discrete support. I am also not looking for an exact simulation, just similar properties and reasonably similar distribution. One idea was using exponential wait times to try to simulate Poisson, but I think the repetitions are excessive and not a great solution for the problem.

Comment: What do you mean "but I don't have access to any" ? There are many, many free software packages, sites, and platforms you could use. If you are on a proprietary HPC platform with no external connections then you could just use C, Fortran, C++ or whatever other compilers are available. Sampling from distributions should be easy in any general purpose language.

Comment: Another option could be to make the draws from the distribution you need in advance, and then access them from your HPC platform.

Comment: I am using a threaded pipeline in a specialized bioinformatics language which doesn't allow me to use external code while threading. You are correct I could make the draws beforehand, but I would need millions of draws  -- storing these as a list beforehand is a pretty clunky solution.

Comment: I am curious as to which solution you adopted in the end.

Comment: @Xi'an I dethreaded the application because it turned out having thread-locks was slowing down the program anyways. So, I could then just call the numpy function which is pretty efficient. If I rethread it, I'd probably just do a floored and bounded normal function because speed is very important for the scale of the application and I can't cycle through multiple geometric sums or generate a long list per iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [screenshot of a reference by NL Johnson et al. (2005)](http://www.du.edu.eg/upFilesCenter/com/1588022165.pdf) summarising the possible approaches based on a Geometric sampling:

[image]

Devroye (1985) indeed does not cover any other algorithm than the Gamma-Poisson version. Note that generating a Poisson variate is feasible from the [Exponential generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46898219/1154578), due to the connection between [the Poisson process and the Exponential distribution](https://transp-or.epfl.ch/courses/OptSim2012/slides/05b-poisson.pdf). It is however *not* the recommended algorithm.

Comment: The documentation for `rnbinom` in `R` says it uses Devroye's (1986) method as a "Gamma mixture of Poissons."  It looks like one really needs a way to draw Gamma variates.  Ahrens & Dieter (1982) published a rejection method in CACM **25**, 47-54.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to generate a large number of value with frequencies their probabilities and then sample from a discrete uniform choice without replacement. By example, suppose your probability of success is $p=1/2$ and the number of failure until the experience has stop is $r=5$.

Then you start by computing the probability of each value using the negative binomial distribution. For the example, you will have $$P(X=0) = 0.03125, P(X=1) = 0.07813, P(X=2)=0.11719, \dots$$

Now, you create a large list of frequency corresponding to those probability. If you want to create a vector of length 100000, then this vector will have 3125 times $0$, 7813 times $1$; 11719 times $2$ and so one.

After, you just choose without replacement from that list the number $n$ of trials you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the inverse CDF method? The CDF of the negative binomial is the regularized incomplete beta function, which is just a ratio of beta functions so it should not be a problem to obtain it with your setup. You can see the details[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426069/finding-the-inverse-of-the-binomial-cumulative-distribution-function). If you want something more fancy tailored specifically to the negative binomial distribution, the standard reference is Devroye's book Non-uniform random variate generation.